# Storing to variable generic EntitySet in C# (Linq To SQL)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-sql, user-controls

I have a two Linq To SQL-generated classes `RequestTowns` and `OfferTowns`, both implement same interface in partial classes.

```
public interface IRouteTable
{      
    int TownID { get; set; }
}

public partial class RequestTowns : IRouteTable
{
   int IRouteTable.TownID
    {
        get { return this.TownID; }
        set { this.TownID = value; }
    }
}
public partial class OfferTowns : IRouteTable
{
     // ... same properties as in RequestTowns
}
```

On the other hand, I have a UserControl, which I want to populate from parent form, calling a following method:

```
EntitySet<IRouteTable> Route { get; set; }

    public void SetSourceObject<TEntity>(EntitySet<TEntity> Source) where TEntity : class, IRouteTable
    {
        Route = Source; // <-- Compiler error is here        
    }
```

Storing the source EntitySet in the variable gives an opportunity to CRUD entities in the other methods of this UserControl. But the implicit converting is denied:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'EntitySet<RequestTowns>' to 'EntitySet<IRouteTable>'
```

I have a different options to handle it:

1. Make a non-generic `UserControl` and get rid of `IRouteTable`
   interface;
2. make a public events `ItemAdded`, `ItemRemoved`,
   `ItemChanged` and handle them in calling form, again in non-generic
   manner;
3. convert `EntitySet` to generic `List`, pass it to `UserControl`
   and pass it back only when the form is closing;
4. cast `EntitySet` someway to make the compiler happy;
5. any other ideas ?

Why `EntitySet`s of interface and class which implementing that interface couldn't be converted implicitly?
How can I make this work in the most elegant way?

Comment: Why would your UserControl depend on EntitySet (data-access-layer object)? I would introduce intermediate data-object to pass into SetSourceObject and inside the UserControl. For example, IEnumerable<IRoute>. And convert whichever entities you need to it. Or just create dummy objects for UnitTests, or while Data-access layer isn't completed yet. I think your 3rd option covers this, so I vote for it. Try decoupling your code.

Comment: @OleksandrPshenychnyy You're right. My control absolutely lacks data-awareness. But I'm afraid that I would have to track object changes on my own. It was the only reason to pass entire EntitySet to the control. However, I will try to apply SoC. Thanks for your reply.